# Flutter Mouse Scroll Wheel Sensitivity

Tags: flutter, listview

I am developing for Windows desktop, using Flutter 2.0.
Scrolling lists using the mouse wheel is somehow boring, how can I add items per wheel-tick settings?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and here is the workaround I've found.
In your widget, where you have your scrolling element (could be a list, or, in my case, a `SingleChildScrollView`), add a `ScrollController` and add a listener to it:

```
class ScrollViewTest extends StatelessWidget
{
  static const _extraScrollSpeed = 80; // your "extra" scroll speed
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  // Constructor.
  ScrollViewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
  {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      ScrollDirection scrollDirection = _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection;
      if (scrollDirection != ScrollDirection.idle)
      {
        double scrollEnd = _scrollController.offset + (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse
                       ? _extraScrollSpeed
                       : -_extraScrollSpeed);
        scrollEnd = min(
                 _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                 max(_scrollController.position.minScrollExtent, scrollEnd));
        _scrollController.jumpTo(scrollEnd);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Container(...),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm. Worked in a stateful widget as well.